# Excel Import Data Parse Error Of Internationaly Formatted Numbers

Tags: c#, excel, parsing, decimal

I'm importing an excel file and i want to add the values to a database. in the database there is a type decimal(18, 5) and i want to add my value 0.00204 to that column in the database. My variable in my model class is of type decimal and i'm trying this code:

```
     Convert.ToDecimal(items[7]);
```

but then i get the error that the input if not correct format.
items is of type object[]. How do i parse the value into a decimal?

all the others work just fine:

```
       product.packSize = Convert.ToInt32(items[3]);
                product.leadTime = Convert.ToString(items[4]);
                product.generalAccessoryCategoryId = Convert.ToInt32(items[5]);
                product.Company = Convert.ToString(items[6]);
                product.Weight = Convert.ToDecimal(items[7]);
```

Comment: Do you get the parse error on this line `product.Weight = Convert.ToDecimal(items[7]);` at run-time or at the time of import from within the Excel application?

Comment: is the excel cell value has any formatting, like currency ?

Comment: Convert.ToDecimal(Convert.ToString(items[7]).replace(',', '.')), try this

Comment: You have left this question open by not marking any of the responses as the answer...did you run into something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for the possible error conditions which may exist at any stage then once safe, extract the string:

```
decimal result;

if ((items!= null) && 
    (items.Any()) && 
    (items[7] != null) && 
    (Decimal.TryParse(items[7].ToString(), out result))
      product.Weight = result;
```

---

After a couple of comments and some investigation, I believe that the items[7] has characters which the convert is not expecting. I have updated my answer above.

```
decimal result;

Decimal.TryParse("0a00204", out result); // Returns false
```

Comment: indeed - always validate your inputs before operating on them... good point ;-)

Comment: items[7] != null is not needed as   Convert.ToDecimal handles it.

Comment: @Dreamweaver yes `ToDecimal` does, but `ToString` does not.

Comment: But that what, why we need to use ToString as Convert.ToDecimal can take object as is.

Comment: Gives me this error: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: @DanielGustafsson I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I had forgott about the swedish stupid handle of comma. We use , instead of . and thats why it said it wasn't a correct input

Answer (score 2):

### EDIT

If you are dealing with a culture issue, you can use this `TryParse(Object, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider, out decimal)` and include your culture (using `en-GB` as an example):

```
decimal.TryParse(items[7], NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"), out product.Weight);
```

---

If the item variables have default values, you can use `TryParse` which will replace the value if it can be parsed, or leave it as the default.  Otherwise you can use the result from `TryParse` (true if it succeeds, false if it fails) to determine whether you need to set the value.  For example:

```
decimal.TryParse(items[7], out product.Weight)
```

OR

```
if(!decimal.TryParse(items[7], out product.Weight))
{
    product.Weight = (decimal)0;
}
```

It may also help to call the `ToString()` method on the object in the array, as sometimes the parse function can have more trouble with interpreting objects than their String reprentations.

Comment: both will not solve the problem but will act as try catch. So the output will be 0 in this case for the exception.

Comment: I had forgott about the swedish stupid handle of comma. We use , instead of . and thats why it said it wasn't a correct input

Answer (score 1):

```
if(items != null && items[7] != null){
   product.Weight = decimal.Parse(items[7].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Gives me this error: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: what is the value of item[7] in watch ?

Comment: That means the data being returned isn't a decimal. Can you try Console.WriteLine(items[7].ToString()); and show me what the value actually is?

Comment: I had forgott about the swedish stupid handle of comma. We use , instead of . and thats why it said it wasn't a correct input